# Check all checboxes in table layout

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have checkboxes that are created dynamically, and I want to press a button a check them all. The button I metioned is located in toolbar and this is the code from it:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_checkall:

                return true;
```

Then I have a table row inside a table layout and this is the code from the table row where I create the checboxes

```
final TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    String[] colText={numerochip};
                    String[] colText2={marcaexploracao,marcaauricular,datanascimento};
                    for(final String text:colText) {
                        final CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
                        ch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
                        ch.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        ch.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        ch.setTextSize(16);
                        ch.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        ch.setText(text);
                        row.addView(ch);
```

So I want to know, how to check all the cheboxes with a click of a button. Thanks

Comment: you need to assign ids to your checkboxes. and later use that id to check it

Comment: My checkboxes are dynamic, I cant assign an id for each and every one of them.

Comment: generate random number each time for loop execute and also store that ids in some arrayList and use it

Comment: Can you show an example below?

Comment: You should not generate an ID, let the System do it for you with View.generateViewId()!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<View> allVIEWS=new ArrayList<>();
```

Now whenever you create new checkboxes just add it in list:

```
CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
......
.......
allVIEWS.add(ch);
```

Now for checking all at once:

```
    for (int i=0;i<allVIEWS.size();i++){
        if (allVIEWS.get(i) instanceof CheckBox){
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) allVIEWS.get(i);
            chk.setChecked(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: how can I use the same button to uncheckall?

Comment: inside of loop,check if that checkbox is selected then uncheck it

Comment: The chk checbox our the original because I dont have acess to them?

Comment: I don't understand you question. what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

1) Create a List of checkboxes. (`List<CheckBox> checkBoxList`)

2) Inside your for loop, after creating checkboxes, add those checkboxes to checkBoxList. (`checkBoxList.add(ch)`)

3) When the button is clicked, use below code.

```
for(CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxList){

       checkBox.setChecked(true);

  }
```